# Unset a header from a proxied response

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I have a proxy configuration under Apache 2.2 which passes all requests for `/blog` to a host I have no control over.

I want to unset a particular HTTP header (`X-Powered-By: PHP`) from the proxied response, so that it is not visible to the browser.

I tried this:

```
ProxyPass /blog http://blog.example.com
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.example.com
Header Always Unset X-Powered-By
```

And also this variation:

```
<Location /blog>
    ProxyPass http://blog.example.com
    ProxyPassReverse http://blog.example.com
    Header Always Unset X-Powered-By
</Location>
```

In both cases, the header is sent through unchanged from the proxy. I also tried `Header Always Edit`, also no effect.

Interestingly, if I use `Header Always Set X-Powered-By Test`, the resulting response contains `X-Powered-By: Test, PHP` - i.e. my value is *added before* the one from the proxy. I suspect `mod_proxy` is running "too late" for `mod_headers` to manipulate the response.

Is there a way to make `Header` run "later", or some other directive which could manipulate the response after it comes back from the proxy.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem in 2.4, except with `Header always edit` (trying to modify cookies).  Did you ever find a solution?  Is `mod_proxy` fundamentally incompatible with `mod_headers`?